# Evaluate a Google Sheets math expression with formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, multiplication, google-query-language

I have some strings inside Google Sheets, containing simple arithmetic expressions:

[image]

Is there a way to evaluate these expressions without the need for writing a script? (i.e. formula only)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(; "select "&A6); 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, wow, so this is essentially a built-in expression evaluator? I'll have to keep that in mind.